# in Stanford iOS7 tutorial, why private property and method(in implementation file) can also be inherited by subclass

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, ios7

his assignment said: All methods (including properties) are inherited by subclasses regardless of whether they are public or private. And if you implement a method in a subclass, you will be overriding your superclass’s implementation (if there is one) regardless of whether the method is public or private.

why private property and method(in implementation file) can also be inherited by subclass.

I remember private property and method is invisible in subclass and subclass cannot use superclass's private property and method.

Comment: It's not an excellent question.  But it looks like you just joined today.  Please don't feel bad, or insulted. Read the help on how/what to ask and try again later ... http://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: Please try to re-write your question in a more readable way. We would like to help but are having trouble understanding the question. If it is a generic question about how objective-c operates the language documentation on Apple's website may be worth reading over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give you a longer answer including the your comment on Calebs answer:

You misunderstood what the author of the tutorial wanted to say. (And I think it is not necessarily your fault.)

Let's have an example:

There is a base class having a public and a private method.

```
@interface BaseClass : …
- (void)publicMethod;
@end

@implementation BaseClass
- (void)_privateMethod
{
    …
}

- (void)publicMethod
{
    …
    [self _privateMethod];
    …
}
@end
```

Let's have a subclass

```
@interface Subclass : BaseClass
- (void)doSomething;
@end

@implementation Subclass
- (void)doSomething
{
    …
    [self publicMethod];
    …
}
@end
```

You know, that `-publicMethod` is inherited from `BaseClass`. Therefore you can send a corresponding  message to `self`. But `-publicMethod` sends a message to `self`, too. Please remember: `self` in `-publicMethod` still points to an instance of `Subclass`, even it's source code is in `BaseClass`. So `[self _privateMethod]` is executed in the context of an instance of `Subclass`. One might ask, if this is possible, because `Subclass` does not know anything about `-_privateMethod`. Yes, it is.

But in `Subclass` you cannot use `_privateMethod`.

Comment: You are welcome. BTW: Subclasses have many implications. This is one reason why "foreign customization" (aka changing the behavior of a class that somebody else developed) is better served with delegation instead of subclassing.

Answer (score 0):

> why private property and method(in implementation file) can also be inherited by subclass

Because every instance of a given class *is also* an instance of that class's superclass. For example, every UIView is also a UIResponder and an NSObject. If a subclass only inherited some of its super class's methods and properties, instances of that class wouldn't be complete and valid instances of the superclass.

Comment: thanks, so private property and method is invisible in subclass and subclass cannot use superclass's private property and method,is it correct?